# SQL Aggregate Performance: converting data types, then serializing, vs. leaving them alone. Which is better?

Tags: c#, sql-server, performance, optimization

I have a custom SQL aggregate in C# that parses and handles tens of millions of records. Now, looking at the code, I can see that some rather odd things have transpired:

1. Everything gets inserted into the aggregate as an Sql Data Type with an accompanying variable name. Example: `SqlString something;`, `SqlInt32 somethingElse;`, et al.
2. For some reason, someone decided to convert these data types to C# data types. `string`, `int`, et al., even though we can use the Sql Data Types from start to finish.
3. After the conversion, and before sending it back to SQL server, the data has to be serialized for SQL Server in order to be accepted again.

I don't see any reason why that should happpen at all. We have to take the additional step of serializing the data to convert it back to a SQL Data Type, in order for it to continue as is. The extra steps of converting the data types, then serializing it before sending, seem to be unnecessary.

Obviously, I should test that out first, to be sure... but I'm not able to due to access restrictions. Wouldn't this be an utter waste of resources? It seems like pointless conversion and serialization, when you can just use the Sql Data Types.

Comment: The bigger performance question, to me, is querying millions of records from the DB just to aggregate them -- something the DB is more than capable of doing in _most_ cases. In testing my own ORM I found that instantiating objects for each row and casting columns to c# types takes a negligible amount of time, even for millions of rows, when compared to pulling a large DB result set and network traffic for that. Every situation is different, of course. YMMV.

Comment: The OP *is* doing it in the database. That is, s/he wrote a custom aggregate function that runs within an appdomain in the SQL Server process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like a red herring (or "red data conversion") to me.  Either the `SqlString` and `string` are the same under the covers, in which case the compiler will do nothing post optimization.  If there is a functional / logical difference then you need to perform the conversion to be able to use the C# types in your code.

In both cases there is no reason to modify the code.

Of course this is all just guessing without actually seeing your code.  In order to understand exactly what you are talking about and give a better answer seeing the actual code would be required.